# Where to begin playing Call of Duty storyline?

Tags: call-of-duty-series

I have played *COD: Black Ops* and now I want to play the complete series. I have COD: MW3, but I've started to think that it has backstory in previous games and I want to play the full storyline.

So, which game should I play first to experience the storyline properly?

Comment: Here's a full story synopsis for the CoD franchise: terrorists, explosions.

Comment: I don't think this question is really opinion based, it's asking where the story continued in Modern Warfare 3 begins.

Answer (score 9):

There are only two story lines in the Call of Duty series:

- The *Modern Warfare* (MW) series (COD4: MW, MW 2, MW 3)
- The *Black Ops* series (COD: Black Ops, Black Ops 2)

Other than that, the story lines for each game are individual and unrelated.

If you feel like the story line in MW3 is worth experiencing in full, you should play COD 4: Modern Warfare, it's sequel COD: Modern Warfare 2 and then the game currently in your possession, Modern Warfare 3.

Comment: And just for clarification, Ghosts is an entirely new story.

Comment: You are correct except for Black Ops. The Black Ops storyline, to a small degree, starts in Call of Duty: World at War. Reznov is a Russian character in the first Black Ops game who first appears in the Russian campaigns of World at War.